# Font matching using image moments in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am creating a code which will tell me how similar two letters are to each other.
For this, I decided to go with `HuMoments` concept in OpenCV.

Given are the images that I have

Co.jpg
[C0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx0rF.jpg)

A.jpg
[A.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ySW.jpg)

Colorado.jpg
[Colorado.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xom8.jpg)

I am reading the images using:

```
im5 = cv2.imread("images/C0.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im7 = cv2.imread("images/Colorado.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im9 = cv2.imread("images/A.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

I am using `cv2.matchShapes` attribute to match:

```
m6 = cv2.matchShapes(im5, im7, cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I2,0)
m8 = cv2.matchShapes(im5, im9, cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I2,0)
```

Finally I am printing the output:

```
print("C0.png and Colorado.png : {}".format(m6))
print("C0.png and A.jpg : {}".format(m8))
```

Here the value closest to zero (0) means perfect match

My output:

```
$ python3 shapeMatcher.py 
Shape Distances Between 
-------------------------
C0.png and Colorado.png : 0.10518804385516889
C0.png and A.jpg : 0.0034705987357361856
```

C0 and Colorado are mismatches which is displayed correctly. The one thing that's baffling me is how is C0.jpg and A.jpg a close match? Am I missing something, what's an alternate way to get a mismatch between C0 and A? Please note value closer to zero means closest match.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes), `cv2.matchShapes` requires contours as input, not images.

[This tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#match-shapes) has an example usage:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('star2.jpg',0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img1, 127, 255,0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img2, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt1 = contours[0]
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2,2,1)
cnt2 = contours[0]

ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1,cnt2,1,0.0)
print ret
```

(Note that `findContours` syntax changed from OpenCV 2 to OpenCV 3.)